# How to convert a timestamp from libgpiod to epoch date and time?

Tags: c++, epoch, c++-chrono, libgpiod

Using `libgpiod` version 1 with C++ bindings, I'm waiting for an event using `event_read` to get line event changes.

I understand that event comes with a timestamp in the `std::chrono::nanoseconds` format:

```
  auto event = line.event_read();
  std::cout << "EVENT TYPE CODE: " << event.event_type << std::endl;
  std::cout << "EVENT TIMESTAMP: " << event.timestamp.count() << std::endl;
```

So, I'm getting output like:

```
EVENT TYPE CODE: 1
EVENT TIMESTAMP: 6603108649419
```

Now I need to convert that timestamp to Linux epoch date and time in seconds, as to register the exact moment the event occurred.

I've tried the following function:

```
unsigned long State::convert_timestamp_to_epoch(std::chrono::nanoseconds timestamp)
{


     // Extract total number of seconds from nanoseconds
    auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(timestamp);

    // Convert seconds to unsigned long
    unsigned long epoch_time = static_cast<unsigned long>(seconds.count());
    std::cout << "CONVERTING:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << timestamp.count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << seconds.count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << epoch_time << std::endl;

    return epoch_time;
}
```

But I'm getting the following result:

```
CONVERTING:
6603108649419
6603
6603
```

None of them are epoch date and times...

How can I convert the `std::chrono::nanoseconds` timestamp that comes from `libgpiod` event to epoch date and time?

Comment: How do you know how to interpret `event.timestamp`? On a first glance, using epoch converter, it doesn't represent milli/micro/nano seconds since epoch.

Comment: Your function is only performing a cast from nanoseconds (regardless if they represent valid epoch timestamp) to seconds, so it's expected that you get the result that is different by order of 1e9. This cast `unsigned long epoch_time = static_cast<unsigned long>(seconds.count());` does nothing (unless count is negative), for [std::chrono::seconds](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) `count` returns signed integer of at least 35 bits (most likely `std::int64_t`).

Comment: Yes; "nanosecond format" doesn't mean anything: x nanoseconds **since when**? You need to study the `libgpiod` docs to find out what that "when" actually is; once you know that, you can readjust the timestamp so the "when" becomes the Unix epoch.

Comment: Current unix epoch time is about 1711630300 seconds so your timestamp apparently measures nanoseconds from something else than start of epoch. Just casting is garbage in -> garbage out.

Comment: OFFS, this was covered in your previous question, which you fail to reference.  The returned timestamp is CLOCK_MONOTONIC for kernels 5.7 and later.  That is equivalent to ```std::chrono::steady_clock::now()```, and you want to convert that to a ```std::chrono::system_clock```.

Comment: Ouch. Converting `steady_clock` to `system_clock` needs a decently advanced C++ compiler -- the g++ 12 that I'm using right now doesn't have `clock_time_conversion` yet, even though it claims to be C++20 (but, I know it's library is rather incomplete). One should probably turn to more Linux-specific calls to convert that clock into something readable.

Comment: If its just an informal conversion where the output doesn't need to be precise, or could even be horribly bad, one could get now() for both clocks as a baseline, subtract the steady_clock now from the timestamp, and add it on top of the system_clock now. But, if Linux has a call that does the conversion, use that.

Comment: `clock_time_conversion` won't do this conversion even in C++20 (fully implemented).  You'll have to go with your "simultaneous now" approximation.

Comment: **libgpiod v2** allows selection of the source clock, but the OP is using **v1** where it is fixed.  Anyway, CLOCK_MONOTONIC is appropriate as he wanted to check the time between two events.  For reasons unstated he now wants the real time too, and if it is for the same application he could probably just read the system time where he is printing the info if he wants to timestamp that.

Comment: The way I typically convert between arbitrary clocks is to read clock A between two reads of clock B, then average those two reads to better estimate the time clock A was read.  I'm not aware of any Linux call that will do the conversion for you, but would be happy to learn of one.

Comment: My apologies if I was being short in my initial comment, but omitting relevant information from your question is just wasting everyone's time.